# Fixed location loading time using OR tools with C#

Tags: c#, traveling-salesman, vehicle-routing, or-tools

Im trying to solve [Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw) using OR tool with C#.
Is it possible to add loading time (fixed duration, that vehicle have to stay at the location after arrival) to every location (no depot, but location)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the loading time to all arcs going out of the node.

In your time transit callback simply return the service time + the travel time.
e.g.

```cs
int transitCallbackIndex = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(
        (long fromIndex, long toIndex) => {
        // Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
        var toNode = manager.IndexToNode(toIndex);
        return data.TimeMatrix[fromNode, toNode] + data.ServiceTime[fromNode]; }
        );
```

Comment: Could you please share some sample or link? thank you

Comment: You have a distance matrix, or some function that returns the distance between 2 nodes. Add the loading time to that computed distance.